# Can we use histogram for color base tracking?

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I am new in image processing, this question may be the noob but I failed to find the answer to this question.

**Problem:** At the start, I got an image of the object which I need to track. after that, I get multiple images in which my object may be rotated, size may be changed (zoomed in or zoomed out). I want to track on the base of color.

**Proposed solution:** the solution that I thought was, I should calculate a histogram of sample image that I got, then using histogram comparison I keep track of that object.

**Failure:** After implementing this solution I came to know it is not the best solution. Because every available method for histogram comparison in OpenCV they will eventually return mean value which will not distinguish exact/similar color match.

Can I use a histogram of detection and tracking ? or is there any good solution ?

PS. in my case object is human.

Comment: Not, colour alone will not be enough, except in very special circumstances (green-screen movie shooting and not even then). I.e. [track this](http://costumerusuk.com/5838-thickbox_default/make-up-fx-aqua-army-soldier-face-and-body-paint-camouflage-fancy-dress-adult-.jpg) based on colour alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using OpenCV Tracking API instead - TLD, for example. There are many different trackers - KCF, Boosting, MedianFlow, etc. Here is an example: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html

You obviously don't need to put video in it - tracker accepts frames in cv::Mat.

Answer (score 0):

No, this wouldn't work. The histogram of an image is not a localized feature, and you're explicitly concerned about only part of an image.